# How to find match of elements and extract matrix

Tags: arrays, matlab, sorting, matrix

```
A=[

17    24     1     8    15
23     5     7    14    16
 4     6    13    20    22
10    12    19    21     3
11    18    25     2     9
26    17    24     3     4]

b= 23;
C= 11;
```

Now, 1st column of matrix `A` must be check to find any element matches with inputs `b` and also `c`. Then, to get matrix

```
D= 

23     5     7    14    16
 4     6    13    20    22
10    12    19    21     3
11    18    25     2     9
```

Comment: So `D=A(find(A(:,1)==b):find(A(:,1)==c),:)`? But what is getting sorted?

Answer (score 0):

Try from these links

[matching indices][1]

[matching data in matrix][2]

[extracting data from matrix][3]